# Azure Reserved Instances - Check allocation

Tags: azure

Would anyone know of a way to check if reserved instances are applied and being used, under the "reservations" page I can see utilization at 100%, however Azure Advisor still shows that adding the virtual machines to Reserved Instances would save money. How would I know if the reservation is being used and against what machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be an article that talks about that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-view-reservations

this article would talk about understanding usage:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-understand-reserved-instance-usage

how discount is applied:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-understand-vm-reservation-charges

you can also view what reservations to buy based on Azure recommendations:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-reservation-apis#find-reservation-plans-to-buy

in principle this means: if you observe 100% usage - means reservation is being applied all the time. as to your question - you might have other vms that can benefit from reservations

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and those links are very helpful :)